# Getting ActionController::RoutingError uninitialized constant while trying to use namespace in Rails routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two controllers `dashboard` and `posts`. Im trying to put the post's `:new, :create, :destroy, :edit, :update` actions within `dashboard` url like this `dashboard/posts/new`. But the im talking to the `new` action in the `posts` controller. Not in the `dash` controller. Here's my `routes.rb` file :

```
resources :posts, :except => [:new, :create, :destroy, :edit, :update]

get 'dashboard', to: 'dash#show'

namespace :dashboard do
   resources :posts, :only => [:new, :create, :destroy, :edit, :update]
end
get 'dashboard/posts', to: 'dash#posts'
```

The two controllers in question are : `dash` and `posts`

Now when I try to visit `http://localhost:3000/dashboard/posts/new` it says :

```
ActionController::RoutingError at /dashboard/posts/new
uninitialized constant Dashboard
```

How to fix this?

Comment: @jmromer Its dash controller but the path is dashboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have two controllers `DashController` and `PostsController`.
And you want to access few of the posts routes within the scope of `namespace` then you can define the routes as below:

```
resources :posts, :only => [:index, :show]

get 'dashboard', to: 'dash#show'

scope :dashboard do
   resources :posts, controller: :posts ,:only => [:new, :create, :destroy, :edit, :update]
end
get 'dashboard/posts', to: 'dash#posts'
```

Answer (score 0):

The constant "Dashboard" can't be found. I think the problem is that you sometimes use `dash` and sometimes use `dashboard`.

Comment: I renamed everything to `Dash` and still getting the same error